# Current user as default for PSCredential parameter of custom CmdletBinding

Tags: powershell

Here's a repro of my Powershell scenario:

```
function Call-Api {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $false)]
        [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
        $Credential = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty
    )

    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://localhost/api" -Method Get -Credential $Credential
}
```

The API has Basic Auth. If I call it like this:

```
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "secret!" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $pwd)
Call-Api $cred
```

Then I get a proper response. But if I call it without credentials like this:

```
Call-Api
```

I get:

> Invoke-RestMethod : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I could of course do an `if`...`else` thing switching on whether `$Credential` is set or not, but that's not very elegant. From [the relevant docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod#-credential) I understand that the default value of *that* cmdlet is "*the current user*".

How can I do something similar? What default do I set for `$Credential` so that it is the current user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the Empty Credential that you are defining as default (I believe this is overwriting the cmdlets own default of current user), then use [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675931.aspx) and only add the `$Credential` Parameter if it present. If it's not present it will use the cmdlets own default value.

```
function Call-Api {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
        $Credential
    )

    $params = @{}

    $params['Uri'] = "http://google.com"
    $params['Method'] = "Get"

    if ($Credential) { $params['Credential'] = $Credential }

    Invoke-RestMethod @params
}
```